# How to turn a pandas pivot_table into a simple table

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame defined by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob'],
    'sales': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
})
```

This DataFrame is easily turned into a pivot table using `pivot_table` :

```
table = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=['name'],
    columns=['year'],
    aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image: table dataframe]

Now I need to turn this DataFrame into a simple JSON array. Unfortunately, the `to_json` method doesn't return a *simple* array:

```
table.reset_index().to_json(orient="records")
```

```
[
    {
      "["name",""]":"Alice",
      "["sales",2019]":400,
      "["sales",2020]":600
    },
    {
     "["name",""]":"Bob",
     "["sales",2019]":1200,
     "["sales",2020]":1400}
]
```

How can I turn the `table` DataFrame into a *simple* (without multiindex) DataFrame?

```
[
    {
      "name":"Alice",
      "2019":400,
      "2020":600
    },
    {
     "name":"Bob",
     "2019":1200,
     "2020":1400
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the `values` param to get rid of the multiindex , also get rid of the lists in the param inside pivot when passing a single column:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(
df,
index='name',
columns='year',
values='sales',
aggfunc=np.sum)

table.reset_index().to_json(orient="records")
```

---

```
'[{"name":"Alice","2019":400,"2020":600},{"name":"Bob","2019":1200,"2020":1400}]'
```

Adding another alternative if you like:

```
out = (df.groupby(['name','year'])['sales'].sum().unstack()
                  .reset_index().to_json(orient='records'))
```

---

```
'[{"name":"Alice","2019":400,"2020":600},{"name":"Bob","2019":1200,"2020":1400}]'
```

Comment: @E.Jaep No , thats not what you did actually , if you compare your and my solutions , you would see that your solution doesnot have the `values=` arg inside pivot whereas mine has , and you pass the column names as  list example: `index = ['name']` , but I dont. Did this not work for you , it works fine for me

Comment: @E.Jaep that's no problem :)